# Issue while Writing Multiple O/P Files in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, multipleoutputs

I have a requirement to split my input file into 2 output file based on a filter condition. My output directory should looks like below:

```
/hdfs/base/dir/matched/YYYY/MM/DD
/hdfs/base/dir/notmatched/YYYY/MM/DD
```

I am using `MultipleOutputs` class to split my data in my map function.
In my driver class I am using like below:

```
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/hdfs/base/dir"));
```

and in Mapper I am using below:

```
mos.write(key, value, fileName); // File Name is generating based on filter criteria
```

This program is working fine for a single day. But in second day my program is failing saying that:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://nameservice1/hdfs/base/dir already exists
```

I cannot use different base directory for the second day.

How can I handle this situation?

**Note:** I don't want to read the input twise to create 2 separate file.

Comment: So your problem is to use the same output directory for all executions.. Am I right?

Comment: Yes... I want to control the actual o/p directory using `MultipleOutputs`(in mapper) not `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath`(in driver class)

Comment: Usually hadoop creates a new directory for each execution. MultipleOutputs class is used to write data to different files. You cannot use the same directory for all executions. You need to delete the base directory already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Custom o/p format class like below

```
package com.visa.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputCommitter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordWriter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;

public class CostomOutputFormat<K, V> extends SequenceFileOutputFormat<K, V>{

    @Override
    public void checkOutputSpecs(JobContext arg0) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public OutputCommitter getOutputCommitter(TaskAttemptContext arg0) throws IOException {
        return super.getOutputCommitter(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public RecordWriter<K, V> getRecordWriter(TaskAttemptContext arg0) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return super.getRecordWriter(arg0);
    }

}
```

and use it in driver class:

```
job.setOutputFormatClass(CostomOutputFormat.class);
```

Which will skip checking of the existence of o/p directory.

Comment: Concept from [this link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-user/201307.mbox/%3C06006DDA5A27D541991944AC4117E7A96E1DB0B1@szxeml560-mbx.china.huawei.com%3E).

Answer (score -1):

You can have a flag column in your output value. Later you can process the output and split it by the flag column.